# Angular: Valores se omiten al agregar el formulario dinámico al formulario de la solicitud principal

Tags: angular, formularios, reactiveformsmodule, angular-reactive-forms

Tengo un formulario dinamico que obtengo de la BD para llenar sus componentes. La logica va algo asi:

Si hay un formulario de servicio en los datos de la respuesta, se crea un formulario dinámico utilizando el servicio formulariosService con el metodo "createForm". Luego, se agrega el formulario dinámico al formulario de la solicitud principal. Finalmente, se actualiza el formulario de la solicitud principal con el formulario dinámico agregado.

Mi problema es que es posible que cuando se crea el formulario dinamico anidados en Angular al añadir el formulario (formulario.addControl) a otro nuevo formulario se omitan valores. Ya que tengo un "mat-select" en donde llenos los campos "tipo_cancer" pero en lugar de llenarlo con los 10 elementos que vienen en el array omite los ultimos dos, y me trae ocho elementos desplegados en mi select

Pero no se porque ocurre esto, a que se debe la variacion, investigando un poco lei que podria ser porque no se especifica correctamente la ruta del control que se está agregando. La ruta es una cadena que indica la ubicación del control en el árbol de formularios anidados. Si se especifica incorrectamente, es posible que el control se agregue en una ubicación inesperada o que se omita por completo.

Realice una demo en stackblitz donde simulo el error, el componente padre es el app.component y el componente hijo es el formulario-solicitud.component [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sangular-z3kula)

El error sucede justo cuando añado el formulario

```
 // Here´s add form
  this.solicitudForm.addControl('formulario', this.infoFormularioForm);
```

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda, realmente llevo rato intentandolo no se que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Tu demo esta mal, no se muestra, debes agregar código para que se tome en serio tu pregunta, debes seguir las reglas de la comunidad y ...bla, bla, bla ... aun así te comento, tu formulario padre debe ser un "FormGroup", dentro debe tener un control tipado como "FormArray" y debes tener un método que hagas push de controles "FormControls"a ese Array... Muestrame codigo y te hecho la mano